# What is a slang but safe for work word for someone who is stubborn or narrow-minded?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I'm trying to write a book and have run into this problem multiple times. I want it to have a strong meaning while remaining respectful. Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with "stubborn" or "narrow-minded"?  What's the criteria for choosing a better word?

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave an example sentence to show how you intend to use the term. That would also get at the criteria that Juhasz is asking about.

Comment: *Dedicated*? *Focused*? *Unwavering*?

Answer (score 1):

**mulish**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mulish)

> - Extremely or irrationally stubborn and intractable.
> - Resembling a mule:

**Mulish** behavior is inflexible and opinionated. One is as stubborn as the famously stubborn mule, an animal that's had this reputation since at least the fifteenth century! Respectful & 'slang'ish' for stubborn!